# Is this proof that the identity function is an automorphism correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I saw this statement (left as an exercise for the reader),

> The identity function $I_E$ is an automorphism for the algebraic structure $(E, \Delta)$.

I tried to prove this as follows,

Consider $(a,b) \in E^2$, here

$$
\begin{align}
I_E(a  \Delta b)
&= a \Delta b && \text{(Def. $I_E$)} \\
&= I_E(a) \Delta I_E(b) && \text{(Def. $I_E$)}
\end{align}
$$

That is, $I_E$ is an automorphism.

But this feels deceptively simple. Is this proof correct?

Comment: Well, identity is always an automorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity is indeed a homomorphism, which is what you proved.

It is *also* bijective, so it is an automorphism.